# How to make gap between two div fixed?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my page, their are two div;s which represent two rows . i want to make the gap between those two div's fixed so that when i use drag and drop, the dropped item goes horizontally to the next item instead of going vertically.
please help
thanks

```
<div id="div1" style="background-color:#778899;height:30px;width:1030px;float:left;">
<b>Columns :</b>

<div id="div2" style="background-color:#778899;height:30px;width:1030px;float:left;">
<b>Rows :</b></div>
```

so in the coloumn div, i m using droppable feature of jquery

```
$('#example-1-2 .sortable-list').sortable({ connectWith: '#example-1-1 .sortable-list' });
```

So the problem is that when I drop an item, the dropped item gets added like a column one below the other. But what I want is that when I drop any item, it should get attached and like a row, one right to another. The column div is below the row div. Therefore, I was asking if we could fix the size of both, and the dropped item will move then in a row like fashion.

Comment: you mind showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: <div id="div1" style="background-color:#778899;height:30px;width:1030px;float:left;">
<b>Columns :</b>

Comment: <div id="div2" style="background-color:#778899;height:30px;width:1030px;float:left;">
<b>Rows :</b></div>

Comment: Please press the edit button below your post and put the code there. (The amount of chars you can have in the comments is limited)

Comment: can u plese give ur mail id, i can send u the code and wat is my exact prob m facing

Comment: No, just press the edit button beneath your question and put it there.

Comment: @MistressDavid
jatin_rajvanshi@yahoo.co.in

Comment: @MistressDavid this is my id
pls send ur id der,
please i need help
very small help, i little doubt m not able to explain here.

Comment: If you can explain it in an email, you can explain it here. I'm sorry, but I don't have time to email you. Just edit your question and explain it here, and we will gladly help you.

Comment: @MistressDavid
ok i will try.
so in the coloumn div, i m using droppable feature of jquery
$('#example-1-2 .sortable-list').sortable({
connectWith: '#example-1-1 .sortable-list'
});

SO THE PROBLEM IS THAT WHEN I DROP AN ITEM, THE DROPPED ITEM GETS ADDED LIKE A CLOUMN ONE BELOW THE OTHER.
BUT WHAT I WANT IS THAT , WHEN I DROP ANY ITEM IT SHOULD GET ATTACHED AND LIKA ROW , ONE RIGHT TO ANOTHER.
THE COLUMN DIV IS BEFORE ROW DIV. THEREFORE I WAS ASKING IF WE COULD FIX THE SIZE OF BOTH, AND THE DROPPED ITEM WILL MOVE THEN IN A ROW LIKE FASHION.

Comment: <div id="div1" style="background-color:#778899;height:30px;width:1030px;float:left;">
<b>Columns :</b>

<div class="dhe-example-section" id="ex-1-2">
<div class="dhe-example-section-content" >
<!-- BEGIN: XHTML for example 1.2 -->
                          <div id="example-1-2">

    <div class="column left first">

     <ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable">
      <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item A</li>
      <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item B</li>
     </ul>

</div>
</div></div></div>

Comment: Press the edit link below your question, and PUT IT THERE.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, I have no idea how to solve your problem. But hopefully, some other person will be able to.

Comment: @MistressDavid
APPRECIATE UR HELP

Comment: A small percentage of the people can be mean here don't take it personally, overall most people are helpful. Everybody has to learn and that is why they have this site.

Answer (score 0):

In your case their can be few problems

1 the dropped item have float

**Solution** remove that float

2 the dropped item have Inline

**Solution** Give that element Display:block so it can break out

the gaping of two divs is not affecting positioning of their child

Also post some of your code so we can see where the problem occurs.
**UPDATE**
use #div1 .sortable-item{display:inline; width:20%;}

the elements are showing block behavior just need to inline the elements

Comment: /* Floats */

.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right;}


.clear,.clearer {clear: both;}
.clearer {
 display: block;
 font-size: 0;
 height: 0;
 line-height: 0;
}

Comment: <div id="div1" style="background-color:#778899;height:30px;width:1030px;float:left;">
<b>Columns :</b>

<div class="dhe-example-section" id="ex-1-2">
<div class="dhe-example-section-content" >
<!-- BEGIN: XHTML for example 1.2 -->
                          <div id="example-1-2">

    <div class="column left first">

     <ul class="sortable-list ui-sortable">
      <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item A</li>
      <li class="sortable-item">Sortable item B</li>
     </ul>

    </div>
</div></div></div>
THIS IS WHERE I AM DROPPING

Comment: /* Layout */

#center-wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 920px;
}


/* Columns */

.column {
 margin-left: 2%;
 width: 32%;
}
.column.first {margin-left: 0;}


/* Sortable items */

.sortable-list {
 background-color: #F93;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 60px;
 padding: 10px;
         
}

Comment: .sortable-item {
 background-color: #FFF;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 cursor: move;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 padding: 20px 0;
 text-align: centre;
         
}

/* Containment area */

#containment {
  background-color: #FFA;
 height: 230px;
        
}


/* Item placeholder (visual helper) */

.placeholder {
 background-color: #BFB;
 border: 1px dashed #666;
 height: 58px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
       
}

Comment: ALL ABOVE IS THE CSS CODE

Comment: AND THIS IS THE ROW DIV
<div id="div2" style="background-color:#778899;height:30px;width:1030px;float:left;">
<b>Rows :</b></div>

SO I WHAT I WANT  IS THAT WEN I DROP ITEM IN COLOUMNS , IS SHOULD GO HORIZONTALLY AND NOT VERTICALLY

Comment: what you want exactly is when items in Columns behave like columns 
and in rows it shows Row Behavior. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: NO NO..
THOSE ARE JUST NAMES COLUMNS AND ROWS
WHAT I WANT IS THAT WHEN I DROP ANY ITEM IT SHOULD MOVE LIKE A SNAKE
ONE BLOCK BY ANOTHER .NOT ONE BELOW THE OTHER.

Comment: use `#div1 .sortable-item{display:inline; width:20%;}` Width as per your need

Comment: UR HELP WAS INDEED VERY USEFULL.
NOW IT WORKS.
THANKS ALOT :)